# Syntax error when using if condition to check a value in the DB in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm receiving a syntax error for the following in a blade `syntax error, unexpected '<'`

```
@if({{$qwinners->closeq}} == 0)
```

What is the error here ?

Comment: the error is not related to your if condition but more so having an unexpected '<' sign somewhere in your file. ctrl + f and find where it is.

Comment: the error is no where related to your condition, you have some unwanted `<` sign in your file. So check closely in entire file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Remove `{{ }}`

```
@if($qwinners->closeq == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

remove curly bracket for in if condition

```
@if($qwinners->closeq == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

`@` is already a php echo. you dont need to use `{{ }}` inside it. use just

```
@if($qwinners->closeq == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

**remove curly bracket  `{{ }}` for in if condition**

```
@if($qwinners->closeq == 0)
```